# How to read first 10 lines of all files that are found, and append them to a new file?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm a developer. I code .NET. I have a lot of code files, that end with `Controller.cs`.

Since I migrated to .NET 6, I want to use a feature it presents.

All of my code files start with `using statements` at the top. For example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Globalization.UserApi
{
    public class LocaleController : Controller
    {
```

Basically, I want to find all `Controller.cs` files, read the first X lines of them, preferably only lines that start with `using`, and append them all to an `AllUsings.txt` file. This way I can decide what `using statements` do I have.

I tried:

```
find / -name "*Controller.cs" 2>&- | xargs sed -n '1,10p' >> /temp/AllUsings.txt
```

But for some reason that I can't understand, it only appends the start of one file to the output.

How should I change this script?

Comment: Does your `sed` support a `-s` or `--separate` command line option?

Comment: @steeldriver, how should I know this?

Comment: `man sed`? `sed --help`?

Answer (score 2):

To get the ten first lines from a file, use `head` with no options:

```bsh
find / -type f -name '*Controller.cs' -exec head {} \; >/temp/AllUsings.txt 2>/dev/null
```

When using `sed`, the editing script `1,10p` would print the 10 first lines of the first file on the utility's command line.  The way you invoke `sed` via `xargs` in your example will make sure to call `sed` as few times as possible (i.e. with as many filenames as possible at once). This is why you get the 10 first lines of the first file only.

To alleviate this, the GNU `sed` utility has a non-standard `-s` option that resets the line number counter for each new file of input. That means you could use it like this to call `sed` as few times as possible for batches of found files:

```bsh
find / -type f -name '*Controller.cs' -exec sed -s -n '1,10p' {} + >/temp/AllUsings.txt 2>/dev/null
```

If you're using a `sed` without this option, call `sed` once per file:

```bsh
find / -type f -name '*Controller.cs' -exec sed -n '1,10p' {} \; >/temp/AllUsings.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Note too that your `sed -n '1,10p'` command is (for a single file) more efficiently written `sed 10q`, i.e., "quit after line 10".

---

It is also safer to redirect the standard error stream to `/dev/null` than to close it with `2>&-`.  Closing the stream could cause the utility to fail if it needs to output something on that stream.

For example:

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "Hello" >"/dev/stderr"; print "Bye"}' 2>/dev/null || echo failed
Bye
```

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "Hello" >"/dev/stderr"; print "Bye"}' 2>&- || echo failed
failed
```

Note that the string `Bye` is never seen in the second example.  The `awk` command fails before being able to output it.